# beamer: How to rescale/change the size of the default zoom level (100%)

Tags: beamer, geometry, zooming

When creating a `beamer` presentation with default geometry settings, the resulting slides are relatively tiny on high-resolution screens. How do you properly rescale the entire presentation such that a 100% zoom level is e.g. four times bigger than usual. The appearance of the presentation must stay unaltered: font size, images, design elements etc. should keep the same size relative to the page size.

Simply changing the page layout with `geometry` does not lead to the desired result. I could take it as a starting point and change each layout parameter manually (font size times four etc.) but this solution is not desired. At the latest when trying to adjust the size of the elements of a theme (e.g. CambridgeUS, see MWE), this approach becomes too complicated, I guess. There *must* be an easier solution.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\geometry{paperwidth=128mm,paperheight=96mm} % this is equivalent to the default settings of beamer with default aspectratio=43
\geometry{paperwidth=512mm,paperheight=384mm} % page is 4x wider/higher but font size etc. will be smaller in relation to the page size
\usetheme{CambridgeUS} % add some design; the design elements also do not stretch when increasing the page size

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{The title}
Some content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I am aware that one can change the zoom, that is chosen when opening the PDF, with `hyperref`'s `pdfstartview` option. But this is not what I want. Basically, the zoom that is 100% per default should be 25%, or: the PDF should be opened at 400% default zoom, which becomes 100%.

One may criticize that the reader can just zoom in the presentation manually, but, depending on the PDF viewer, the maximum zoom may be limited. While Acrobat Reader can zoom up to 6400%, Google Chrome can only go up to 500%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `pgfpages` package to resize the result to a bigger page size

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[physical paper height=384mm,physical paper width=512mm]

\usetheme{CambridgeUS} % add some design; the design elements also do not stretch when increasing the page size

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{The title}
Some content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(be careful if you have multimedia content like videos or similar on your slides, they might be shown at the wrong position)